# How Does the Silverlight Client Talk to the Server in a 3 Tier Lightswitch Application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch, 3-tier, lightswitch-2012

I've picked up a legacy 3 tier Lightswitch application, and need to deploy it to a new server in my work.

The client is a Silverlight application deployed to a file server where my clients can access it, and the Server is hosted on an IIS server.

I've managed to get the Server application running on the new Server. Now, I need to have the desktop client talk to that server. However, I can't find, and don't understand how to configure my client Silverlight application to look in a different location for my Lightswitch server than it previously was.

Can someone please explain how the Silverlight client in a 3 tier Lightswitch application knows where to look for, and how to communicate with the Server?

Comment: I'd start by looking for a configuration xml file containing connection strings and update them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the IIS Server is correctly set up, you should just be able to use a browser to download and install the current version of the desktop application (with correct configuration) from it.

The url format for the request is:

```
http[s]://{servername}[:port]/{applicationname}/
```

If you're not sure of the application name, use IIS Manager to browse the site where the application is installed. The directory name where the files are located is the application name. So assuming your IIS server is 10.0.0.1, that the site is on port 80, that you don't require https, and that your application is called Jamie_Butler, the URL would be:

```
http://10.0.0.1/Jamie_Butler
```

Probably best to uninstall the previous version from the client first.

I haven't set up an application like that for a while (and to be honest never that much anyway) so I don't have an example to hand and my recollection might be wrong. Shout back if something doesn't make sense.

Phil

Comment: Hi Phil, this seems like the most promising path, and I'm almost there, but when I navigate to the website, I'm only shown a small Silverlight Logo which directs me to the download page for silverlight. Do you know what might be causing that?

Comment: Nevermind, that was happening because I was viewing it in Chrome when I should have been viewing it in IE. It's all working now, thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you have to jump through hoops to get Silverlight working in Chrome now and even those hoops will probably be withdrawn by the end of the year. Glad it's working for you now.